# Calculate total sum of all the numbers previously entered in a field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

i want to calculate the total of the numbers entered by the user. After a user has added item name and the amount, i want to display the total. How can i do this? i just need to display the total.

For example
item name : 10
item name : 5
total = 15

http://jsfiddle.net/81t6auhd/

```
<body>

<header>
    <h1>Exercise 5-2</h1>
</header>


    <p>Item: <input type="text" id="item" size="30">
    <p>Amount: <input type="text" id="amount" size="30">
    <p><span id="message">*</span>
    <p><input type="button" id="addbutton" value="Add Item" onClick="processInfo();">



<script>
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var myTransaction = [];
                              
function processInfo ()
{    
     var myItem = $('item').value;
     var myAmount = parseFloat($('amount').value);
     var myTotal = myItem + ":" + myAmount;
     var myParagraph = $('message');  
     

     myParagraph.innerHTML = "";
     myTransaction.push(myTotal);
     myParagraph.innerHTML += myTransaction.join("<br>"); 
        
};

(function () {
    $("addbutton").onclick = processInfo;
    
})();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: do you want the some of both the input fields value?

Comment: What's the point in adding the "item" (string) if you don't store that anywhere?   Store item+amount in an array, then sum as and when desired.  You could also output them and sum from the DOM, along with a `[x]` button to remove an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to stored the previous value somewhere in memory to be able to reuse it at next iteration

one proposal can be to stored it in dataset of the field

```
     if ($('amount').dataset.previous) {
      myAmount += parseFloat($('amount').dataset.previous);
     }
     $('amount').dataset.previous = myAmount
```

```js
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var myTransaction = [];
                              
function processInfo ()
{    
     var myItem = $('item').value;
     var myAmount = parseFloat($('amount').value);
     if ($('amount').dataset.previous) {
      myAmount += parseFloat($('amount').dataset.previous);
     }
     $('amount').dataset.previous = myAmount;
     var myTotal = myItem + ":" + myAmount;
     var myParagraph = $('message');  
     

     myParagraph.innerHTML = "";
     myTransaction.push(myTotal);
     myParagraph.innerHTML += myTransaction.join("<br>"); 
        
};

(function () {
    $("addbutton").onclick = processInfo;
})();
```

```html
<p>Item: <input type="text" id="item" size="30">
<p>Amount: <input type="text" id="amount" size="30">
<p><span id="message">*</span>
<p><input type="button" id="addbutton" value="Add Item" onClick="processInfo();">
```